# Запуск Symfony Process в несколько потоков

Tags: php, symfony, процесс, асинхронность, symfony4

Есть код:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

while (count($this -> allApps) > 0 ){
$app = array_shift($this -> allApps);

$process = new Process(['/usr/bin/php','task.php','GetData',$app['app']]);
$process->run();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

self :: log ($app);
self :: log ("Accs left: " . count($this -> allApps) . "\n");
}
```

В один поток из массива $this -> allApps берутся данные, запускается внешний php скрипт, после его выполнения, процедура повторяется, пока массив не будет пустым.

Знаю что Process Component может работать асинхронно.

Скажите, есть возможность запускать по 3-10 воркера(process) внутри while, и по мере освобождения одного из них - давать ему новую задачу из $this -> allApps?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вы смогли реализовать данную задачу правильно, вам стоит использовать очереди. Обратите внимание на [RMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) и реализацию функционала в Symfony - [RabbitMQBundle](https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle)